# Firefox can't find external CSS using absolute file path

Tags: html, css

On my web page I have the following line in the `<head>` element:

```
<link type="text/css" href="C:/myApps/app1/images/css/12.02/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I go to view that page in Firefox 11.0, it is obvious that the `main.css` is not being loaded. If I go to view page source, I see the `<link>` element (above) in the HTML, but when I click it I get the following error:

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (c) isn't associated with any program.

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
<link type="text/css" href="file:///C:/myApps/app1/images/css/12.02/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

might work

Edit: as per the other answers, this is when you want to use a css file on your local machine, if the website will be hosted then you'll need to use a relative path.

```
<link type="text/css" href="images/css/12.02/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The above assumes that your html file with the link in is located in your "app1" folder.

Martyn

Answer (score 3):

you need to insert an url/uri => `file:///C:/myApps/app1/images/css/12.02/main.css`

Comment: damn me and my slow typing :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cas change your css path

```
<link type="text/css" href="C:/myApps/app1/images/css/12.02/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

into

xxx.css replace into correct path

```
<link type="text/css" href="xxx.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```